# 3 divs swicthes using javascript when site reload

Tags: javascript, html

i want a switch 3 divs like:
first time site reloaded show div 1
second time site reloaded show div 2
third time site reloaded show div 3
again repeat from div 1

i have the following code

```
  var a = localStorage.getItem("visits");
   a++;
  localStorage.setItem("visits", a);
if(a % 2 != 0){
document.getElementById("1").style.display="block";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("2").style.display="block";
}
```

in css div (display:none)

but this does not suits my requirement

Comment: i want to switch 3 divs 1st time site reload 1st div,2nd time 2nd and 3rd time 3rd then repeat from 1st

Comment: Well you could change the code to switch between 3 divs and then we'll help debug. You are trying to make us write your code. Please implement an attempt for your new requirement and update your question with it.

Comment: sorry i tried but could'nt think of a logic to do so thats why i am looking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to handle the first load (When there is no `visits` stored in the `localstorage`).

```
var a = localStorage.getItem("visits") || 0; 
// if the item found in localstorage it'll store it in the a
// otherwise, it'll store 0
```

Then, after incrementing the `a` using `a++`, you need to check if a now is greater than 3. In this case, you should start from 1 again.

```
a++;
if(a > 3) a = 1;
```

Since your DIVs IDs are numeric, you don't need the if-else statements. Just use the `a` to select the wanted div.

```
localStorage.setItem("visits", a);
document.getElementById(a).style.display = "block";
```

Here's the full code:

```
var a = localStorage.getItem("visits") || 0; 
a++;
if(a > 3) a = 1;
localStorage.setItem("visits", a);
document.getElementById(a).style.display = "block";
```

Comment: works thank you i used if elseif statements in the code and it worked very will really appreciate your support

Answer (score 0):

You can easily repeat the numbers via the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder). Each time the page loads it will increment the `index` stored in localStorage.

Resulting:

1. `index` = `0` | `id` = `1`
2. `index` = `1` | `id` = `2`
3. `index` = `2` | `id` = `3`
4. `index` = `0` | `id` = `1`
5. etc ...

```
const index = +localStorage.getItem("visits") || 0;

document.getElementById(index + 1).style.display = "block";

localStorage.setItem("visits", (index + 1) % 3);
```